# Access Array Element from Inside a Function in a For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm looking to store the ids of multiple forms in an array, and then use those ids to validate the forms using .valid(). The forms will have unique ids orderProducts1, orderProducts 2 etc etc and I need to validate a select drop down in each form but don't want to have to write lots of javascript to do so.

I have managed to store the form ids in an array but I can't get the value of the array element to use in my function.

I'm not much of a programmer so any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Example below:

```
var productForm = [];

var formID = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for (var i = 0; i<formID.length; i++) {
  productForm.push(formID[i].id);
}

for (var i=0; i<productForm.length; i++)    {
    $(function()    { 
        $('I NEED THE ARRAY ELEMENT HERE #item_add').click(function()   {
            if ($("select[name=packageOption]").valid())    { 
            } 
            else    { 
                alert('Please choose a package option');
                return false;  
            }  
        }); 
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(
    $('form').on('click','#item_add',function(){
        if ($(this).find("select[name=packageOption]").valid()){
            /* Do your fun stuff here */ 
        } 
        else    { 
            alert('Please choose a package option');
            return false;  
        }  
    });
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be adding a click listener to all elements with the id `item_add` that are inside a form.

You can achieve this on a much simpler way than what you are doing.

JQuery allows to match any number of elements according to the given selector.

So you can simply do this :

```
$('#item_add form').click(function(){
    /* Your handler */
});
```

However an important note here : there should always be only one element with a given ID.

From [W3Schools ID page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) :
*The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).*

Instead of having item_add as your elements' id, make it one of their classnames. One element can have any number of classnames separated by spaces and any number of elements can have the same classname.

Your solution would stay pretty much the same except one character :

```
$('.item_add form').click(function(){
    /* Your handler */
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I will have maybe 25+ different forms on my page and each form will have the unique id. So instead of writing $('#formName1').click(function()) and then $('#formName2').click(function()) etc I was looking to store the id of the form in an array and then loop through the array pulling the form id out of that array so like $('#arrayItem1').click(function()). Does that makes sense?? Thanks.

Comment: Even if the IDs are different, if the handler function is the same you should use a selector that will match all the forms at once. It can be `form` if you do not have any other form in your DOM tree or a class that you add to all of these. IDs are very useful for some stuff but are used much less often than classes.